# Error in "GRANT ALL ON database.* TO command

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run a script containing command `GRANT ALL ON BIDB.* TO biouser@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by 'bio123!';`  . But somehow i am getting an error saying `biouser is not valid at this position and an identifier is expected`. I have attached an image of the issue.

[image]

Comment: The error message seems to be related to missing quotes. Please try :
`GRANT ALL ON BIDB.* TO 'biouser'@'localhost' ;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it was removed in mysql 8.0 see [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)

Use instead

```
CREATE USER 'biouser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by 'bio123!';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON BIDB.* TO 'biouser'@'localhost';
```